# where to place app id for javascript share for facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, share

hello im having a small issue of where to exactly place the appID from facebook for the share function to work. I get the error. "The parameter app_id is required"

edit: sorry i forgot to mention how i want it to work. i need it to grab to the current url to share on facebook for multiple products.

EDIT2: reupdated the code but still am getting an error

```
<h4>SHARE THIS!</h4>

<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>


                <a class="social gp" href="#">google+</a>
                <a class="social pt" href="#">pintrest</a>
                <a class="social fb" id="fb" href="#" >facebook</a>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId:'2**************', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true,});
};
</script>
<script>
document.getElementById('fb').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    display: 'popup',
    method: 'share',
    href: 'window.location.href',
}, function(response){});
}

</script>
                <a class="social tw" href="#">twitter</a>
                <a class="social ig" href="#">instagram</a>
```

Comment: You should not put `window.fbAsyncInit` inside a click handler – the SDK will likely have finished loading before and found no `fbAsyncInit` event handler defined. And when the click event occurs, you are just assigning a function reference to a window property has has no special meaning any more. So put that event outside of the click handler, and keep the `FB.ui` call in …

Comment: ok tried that and still getting an error. im also asking the people who setted up the facebook id if that is the correct id.

Comment: May I suggest another easier way to do the same thing (to share on Facebook)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking for the basic JavaScript SDK setup, it should go directly under the opening body tag (along with the snippet to asynchronously load the SDK) like so:

```
<body>    
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '{your-app-id}',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.0'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    <!-- Your code here -->
</body>
```

Here's where it's described in their quickstart guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.1.

Then, later, you should just be able to use the share dialogue wherever you need it:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```

Here's where that's described: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog